# How to run two video frames in parallel using a single camera

Tags: python, opencv, parallel-processing

I'm creating two different frames using a single cam output. I need to process them separately and run them in parallel.

```py
Import cv2
Import numpy as no

cap=videocapture(0)

def frame_1():
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("frame1",frame)
        print("a")

def frame_2():
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("frame2",frame)
        print("b")
        print("c")

while True:
         frame_1()
         frame_2()
         If cv2.waitkey(1)&00ff=ord("z"):
                  break
 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyallwindows()
```

I need these two frames to work in parallel. When I run the code the two frames appear, but one frame freezes while it runs the other one. And I can also find the difference using the print option. First it prints the a, then it prints b and c, like that. How can I make these frames work in parallel?

Comment: Be aware of multiple typos in your code

Comment: That means ?? I can't understand what you are saying??

Comment: It is possible if you read from IP camera, but not possible with USB or integrated cameras, but you need to run each in different threads.

Comment: It means that you have some errors in the code you have copied, for example `Import` should be `import` and some other ones. A Typo is a small mistake like in this case I instead of i.

Comment: Your code (after fixing the typos and syntax errors) works in my Windows 10 tablet using either front or rear camera.

Comment: i typed  this question in my phone so that i cant maintain syntax ok

Comment: this code works i know that but not parallely it works seperately

Comment: Can you clarify what your posted code belongs, parallely or separately?

Comment: my code runs the both frame.but it  runs seperatley we can see the difference by printing some values.but i need this program to be run parallely like threading

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code using threads:

```
import cv2
import threading

def frame(win, chars):
    while not flag.is_set() and cap.isOpened():
        rv, frame = cap.read()
        if rv:
            cv2.imshow(win, frame)
            for c in chars: print(c)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == 27: break
    flag.set() # terminate other threads as well

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag = threading.Event()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=frame, args=('win1','a'))
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=frame, args=('win2',('b','c')))
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

cap.release()
```